# Convert tuple and string to list

Tags: python

How to convert tuple and a string to list without looping through each of the items of the tuple such as:

```
n = (102, '(24, -20)') 
#to become (102,24,-20)
```

Comment: Well, first off, it's a tuple. You can't do anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular situation, you can use `eval`.

```
>>> n = (102, '(24, -20)') 
>>> n = list(n)
>>> n
[102, '(24, -20)']
>>> n[1] = eval(n[1])
>>> n
[102, (24, -20)]
>>> new = (n[0], [1][0], n[1][1])
>>> new
(102, 1, -20)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example you show, you can do this:

```
exec('a='+n[1])
n = [n[0]]
n += list(a)
```